# Could you please help me write a test class for the following code:

Tags: trigger, unit-test

```
trigger TicketTrigger on Ticket__c (before insert) 
{
    List<Id> cusIdList = new List<ID>();
    List<Ticket__c> updatedTckt = new List<Ticket__c>();
    for(Ticket__c ticket :trigger.new)
    {
        cusIDList.add(ticket.Customer__c);

    }
    List<Customer__C> cuslst = [SELECT Id,No_of_visits__c FROM Customer__c where Id IN: cusIdList];
    List<Offer__c> offList =  [SELECT Id, RepeatingNo__c, Name, Discount__c FROM Offer__C ];
    for(Customer__c cus: cuslst)
    {
        for(Ticket__c tckt :trigger.new){
            if(tckt.Customer__c == cus.Id){
                for(Offer__c offer : offList){
                    if(offer.RepeatingNo__c == String.valueOf(cus.No_of_visits__c)){
                        tckt.Offers__c=offer.Id;
                        tckt.Discount__c=offer.Discount__c;
                        tckt.Total_Amount__c=((Integer.valueOf(label.Adult_Ticket_Price)*tckt.Number_Of_Adult__c) + 
                            (Integer.valueOf(label.Child_Ticket_Price)*tckt.Number_Of_Child__c) +
                            (Integer.valueOf(label.Senior_Ticket_Price)*tckt.Number_Of_Senior__c))*(100-offer.Discount__c)/100;

                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            //updatedTckt.add(tckt);
        }


    }
    /**if(updatedTckt.size()>0){
        insert updatedTckt;
    }**/
}
```

---

@isTest
public class TestTicketTrigger 
{

```
private static testMethod void testTicket()
{

    Customer__c cus = new Customer__C();
    Ticket__c tkt = new Ticket__C();

    cus.No_of_Visits__c=3;
    cus.Customer_AADHAR_ID__c=523456789012;
    cus.Customer_Email__c='suryankaggarwal1@gmail.com';
    cus.Customer_Gender__c='Male';
    cus.Customer_Phone__c='8950460945';
    cus.Customer_Address__c='105 llaalala';

    tkt.Customer__c=cus.Customer_ID__c;
    tkt.Booking_Status__c='Not Confirmed';
    tkt.Date__c=02-02-2019;
    tkt.Number_Of_Adult__c=2;
    tkt.Number_Of_Child__c=2;
    tkt.Number_Of_Senior__c=2;


    Offer__c off=[Select Id,discount__c from Offer__c
                  where Offer__c.RepeatingNo__c = '3'];

    System.assertEquals('a056F00000nScu7', Offer__c.Id);
    System.assertEquals('50', Offer__c.discount__c);        

}
```

}

See i reached till here but code coverage is not proper

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If you're new to unit testing, a good place to start would be the [Apex Testing module on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing). [How to write good unit tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) is another resource.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely write the test class: it might take you a few hours to learn how via Trailhead but it is a fundamental skill you will need to do development work on Salesforce. Note that for a "before insert" trigger to run, you need to insert records in the test.

When you have passing tests, refactor this logic:

```
for(Customer__c cus: cuslst){
    for(Ticket__c tckt :trigger.new){
        if(tckt.Customer__c == cus.Id){
            for(Offer__c offer : offList){
               if(offer.RepeatingNo__c == String.valueOf(cus.No_of_visits__c)){
```

because this sort of loop nesting results in exponential slowdown as the number of records increases which could leave you hitting CPU governor limits in production. See e.g. [Fixing a common cause of System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/).

Also look to limit the number of offer rows that you query to only those that are relevant. Otherwise more potential governor limit problems.